# Powershell - Get partial name as Variable

Tags: powershell, variables

First posting here, and I'm a beginner in Powershell (Or most script, in the matter of fact).
What a try to do here is to take a part of a name file, and use it later To download a file from our server with the same name.

```
$name = Get-childitem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*.ost" -name
$username = $name.Remove($name.IndexOf('@'))
Write-Output $Username
```

I only get the the file name without what I put between ${.}

Thanks for any help

Comment: That's because no variable with name `$UserName` is defined. You call `Get-childitem` but do nothing with it. Did you mean to get `(Get-childitem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" -File).FullName` ?

Comment: More logical that way (This is my third script, so, many command I still not used yet). What I want, is to extract $Username from the file named Name.Lastname@Something.com - Name.Lastname.OST, but don't know how to extract only Name.Lastname part of the file name. (And thanks for the fast answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string on the `@` and grab only the first item from the resulting array:

```
$name = "FirstName.LastName@company.com - more text you don't care about.ost"

# String.Split() returns an array of strings, `[0]` gives us the first item in that array
$username = $name.Split('@')[0]
```

Alteratively, *remove* everything from the original string beginning at the first `@`:

```
$username = $name.Remove($name.IndexOf('@'))
```

Comment: Thanks ! Able to get what I wanted ! Edit the final work in my text.